# Don't find TimePicker 24h format javascript (CDN)

Tags: javascript, symfony, cdn, timepicker

In my Symfony 4 project I need to implement a TimePicker field.

For that I would need a plugin or something like that, to be able to turn a simple text field into TimePicker.

I would need something that looks like this:

[image]

A TimePicker in 24h format, without the display of PM or AM.

And with ease of installation (CDN import for example).

At http://bootstrapformhelpers.com/timepicker/#jquery-plugins, you have to install a lot of things, and that's not what I'm looking for.

And on other sites the design is really not good, I'm looking for something simple and without the display of PM and AM.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic: _“Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.”_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-formhelpers/2.3.0/css/bootstrap-formhelpers.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-formhelpers/2.3.0/js/bootstrap-formhelpers.js"></script>

<div class="bfh-timepicker" data-time="08:00">
</div>
```